# Как мне исправить ошибку метода undefined method `call' for "ы\n":String (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, методы

```
/home/arhich/rubytut/lesson12/game.rb:22:in `ask_next_letter': undefined method `call' for "ы\n":String (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  caller
    from viselitsa2.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

22 строка

```
letter = STDIN.gets.encode.("UTF-8").chomp
```

8 строка

```
game.ask_next_letter
```

Comment: Мб вы приведете код, который эту ошибку вызывает?

Answer (score 1):

#### Сообщение об ошибке прямо говорит, в чём дело

```
letter = STDIN.gets.encode.("UTF-8").chomp
#                         ^
```

...то же самое, что и:

```
letter = STDIN.gets.encode.call("UTF-8").chomp
#                         ^^^^^
```

`encode` был вызван без аргументов. Такая форма действительно есть и преобразует в `Encoding.default_internal`; возвращает, естественно, строку.
Если вы хотели передать `("UTF-8")` именно в `encode`, то у вас там точка лишняя.

Такой синтаксис существует, чтобы `Proc`-подобные объекты было не слишком громоздко вызывать, по сравнению с обычными вызовами методов. Но у вас он образовался случайно.